# What is Android Fullbackup on Android 5.1?

Tags: android, android-backup-service

Android auto-backup is not supposed to exist on Android 5.1, but I can still run the following command:

```
adb shell bmgr fullbackup <PACKAGE>
```

on Android 5.1. Why does it exist in Android 5.1 if auto-backup isn't available? What does it do? The same as on Android 6?

Also what is `@pm@` and why do we need to do it for auto-backup:

```
adb shell bmgr backup @pm@ && adb shell bmgr run
```

For reference:
[Testing Android Backup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/testingbackup#TestingBackup)

Comment: As far as I remember the feature to backup app data to GDrive was first only available to apps which had enabled this in the app code. If I understand the description correctly those commands allow to force a backup to GDrive even for apps that do not support or configure backup.

Comment: Ok, but this was supported already in Android 5.1? Because what they call auto-backup is not supposed to exist prior to Android 6.

Comment: I think backup to GDrive was introduced in Android 5.

Comment: Aha. Interesting. So, it was only automatically done in Android 6 first? It is all very poorly documented.

Comment: What triggers the backup to GDrive then? Is is scheduled automatically?

Comment: I don't remember. Most likely the app was responsible for triggering it.

Comment: The app itself? That is strange. Why do you think that?

Comment: Because the app knows best when app data have changed and thus a backup makes sense.

Comment: Normally you would do BackupManager#dataChanged() then backup would run sometime later. Maybe it is the same here.

Comment: Just to make it clear: When I write that the app itself triggers backup then I was referring to the method BackupManager#dataChanged() JohnyTex mentioned. Those adb commands are just for testing and debugging purposes in case the developer wants to manually trigger a backup or restore.

Comment: Do you know how this feature was enabled on Android 5.1? In flag via manifest?

Comment: There is a 10 year old example app that demonstarted the AndroidManifest.xml entrie and the necessary classes to implement: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/BackupRestore/AndroidManifest.xml BTW: I was wrong that concept was introduced in Android API 8 (Android 2.2) but I don't think a backup to GDrive was already possible at that time. Some descriptions talk about backup to "external storage"...

Comment: It seems to do only the old key/value backup and not the full backup, since it declared a Backup Agent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240727/discussion-between-robert-and-johnytex).